# How to get membership badges for YouTube live chat messages?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I've been poking around at the YouTube live chat API to render out a custom chat feed, and was wondering how I can show membership/sponsorship badges next to users like the YouTube site itself does?

Looking at a response from the API, I can see that YouTube does tell me the user is a member/sponsor, but it doesn't include at what level/duration nor what badge image should be shown:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#liveChatMessage",
  "etag": "MHpDf4piJnYR2X3lP-7mwBavfWM",
  "id": "LCC.CjgKDQoLd1VwYUIzYTdkVW8qJwoYVUNEWExPVjNTMEdUd21EOFY4R1A2dzlREgt3VXBhQjNhN2RVbxI7ChpDSVRodDQzS292VUNGZVV0clFZZHNJRUwzZxIdQ1B1VHJiYV9vdlVDRllhRGdnb2RaUE1LanctMjY",
  "snippet": {
    "type": "textMessageEvent",
    "liveChatId": "Cg0KC3dVcGFCM2E3ZFVvKicKGFVDRFhMT1YzUzBHVHdtRDhWOEdQNnc5URILd1VwYUIzYTdkVW8",
    "authorChannelId": "UCYC1zf9Dznp-xpe9rwEopLQ",
    "publishedAt": "2022-01-08T16:31:12.317Z",
    "hasDisplayContent": true,
    "displayMessage": "Instead of waiting 30 seconds you had to spam facecam now you get a 5 minute timeout",
    "textMessageDetails": {
      "messageText": "Instead of waiting 30 seconds you had to spam facecam now you get a 5 minute timeout"
    }
  },
  "authorDetails": {
    "channelId": "UCYC1zf9Dznp-xpe9rwEopLQ",
    "channelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYC1zf9Dznp-xpe9rwEopLQ",
    "displayName": "Cody Kerley",
    "profileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQFiwv-x6ukfTOh7pD7WlCe7Ss1AB5wH7QAF53uiQ=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
    "isVerified": false,
    "isChatOwner": false,
    "isChatSponsor": true,
    "isChatModerator": true
  }
}
```

But if I look at how this message was shown in the YouTube chat itself, the user has the correct membership badge for their level/duration, specific to this channel, and the tooltip also shows you the level/duration of the membership/sponsorship:

[image: YouTube chat screenshot with membership badge]

How can I get this information from the API for each chat message so that I can render the badge correctly myself?

Cheers.

Comment: I would like to help you however even on the web interface I am unable to reproduce your picture. Could you share us a YouTube video id with a chat rebroadcast ? Can "random" users see this information or only you ? In the case of "random" I could try to reverse engineer.

Comment: Yes, this information is available to anyone that views the live chat for the stream, including anonymous users -- I just don't see it in the YouTube API anywhere. The demo message included above was from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUpaB3a7dUo, which was just a random live stream I picked to test my code.

Comment: Just to make sure does your request is about live that ended or live currently broadcasting or both ?

Comment: Looking to solve this for an active live chat, one that is currently broadcasting :)

Answer (score 2):

As you said there doesn't seem to be any official YouTube Data API v3 endpoint providing membership badges for YouTube live chat messages.

However I reverse-engineered YouTube live chat messages and here is the solution:

1. Get a `continuation` token starting with `0ofMyAO` (there seems to be 2 that both work) by executing (don't forget to change `VIDEO_ID` with your YouTube live video id):

   ```
   curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=VIDEO_ID' -H 'User-Agent: Firefox/99'
   ```
2. Use this `continuation` token to fetch all pieces of information about current YouTube live chat messages by executing (don't forget to change `CONTINUATION_TOKEN` with the `continuation` token you grab at step 1., note: don't care about the key it's not a YouTube Data API v3 key):

   ```
   curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/live_chat/get_live_chat?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"context":{"client":{"clientName":"WEB","clientVersion":"2.9999099"}},"continuation":"CONTINUATION_TOKEN"}'
   ```
3. Likewise you'll get all pieces of information about current YouTube live chat messages since the moment you grab the `continuation` token at step 1. **however `continuation` token seems to expire every 5 minutes so grab a new one** from the response of step 2. or by doing step 1. once again.
   Note 0: during the 5 minutes window, you can execute step 2. as many time as you want to get messages in real time
   Note 1: I recommend you to change the `continuation` token every 4 minutes in order not to miss any message
4. I let you understand the JSON response that contain the pieces of information you are looking for

Note: at step 1. you retrieve recent message sent before your request but it's in HTML format and not JSON this time