# Profile picture and messages of YouTube live chat

Tags: youtube, chat

how can I get the profile picture of people that, for example, say "hello"  in the YouTube live chat ?

Comment: Are you talking about a live currently being broadcasted or that already ended or both ?

Comment: sorry for the long response, i was in vacation. I'm talking aboout a live that is currently broadcasted

Comment: You can retrieve the informations you are looking for with [such an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70660765/7123660).

Comment: how yeah now i know how curl works and i can do what i want to do thanks !!